# POST and GET images to/out of MongoDB in Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, multer

I´m making an angular application, which gives users the possibilities, to manage their projects. I´ve got nodeJS & express serveside and MongoDB as my database.

I want to achieve, that a user can upload media(images under 16MB, so no need to use GridFS) to their projects and that you can display which project, has which media attached.

I´m not getting the images, nor an error. How can I pass the `project_Id` from angular, to my route, to find the media attached to the project? Is this way of trying to POST and GET the media the right way?

**The model for projects and for media:**

```
var mediaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        media       : {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
        project_id  : String,
        updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

---

```
var projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        author      : String,
        name        : String,
        description : String,
        tags        : String,
        updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now },
        active      : {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

**The routing**

```
var Media = require('./models/media.js'); 
//GET all the media
app.get('/uploads/', function(req, res, next){
    Media.find(function (err, media){
        if (err) return next (err);
        res.json(media);
    });
});
//GET one item
app.get('/uploads/media/:projectId', function(req, res, next){
    Media.findOne(req.params , function (err, media){
        if (err) return next (err);
        res.json(media);
    });
});
```

**Managing the uploads**

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
 rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename+Date.now();
  },
onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
  console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
},
onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
  console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
  done=true;
}
}));    

var Media = require('./app/models/media.js'); 
//POST media to the upload directory
app.post('/uploads/', function(req, res){
   if(done==true){
    Media.create(req.body, function(err, post){            
        console.log(req.files);
        res.end('File uploaded');          
    });
   }
});
```

**Angular Controller**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('projectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.myVar = false;
        $scope.toggle = function() {
            $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar
        };
        $http.get('/profile/project/').then(function (res){
            $scope.projects = res.data;
        });


        //GET Media
        var projectId = {{projects._id}};
        $http.get('/uploads/media' + projectId).succes(function(data){
            console.log('Medien-Daten erhalten');
            $scope.media = data;
        });
    });
```

Kind regards from Germany,
David

**Update (new Errors)**

Trying to implement a solution, I get problems with my scopes. When I´m adding the $http.get for the media, my other scope seem to fetch no data... they are shown like this:[image: scope doesnt work]

**Update 2(scope error fixed)**

Fixed the error in the controller. I hadn´t defined a var for projectId, that caused the error.
Managed to make the GET request work, and my application is looking for entries in the database. But i can´t manage to see any..

Comment: read up on parameterized routes in express  `app.get('/uploads/media/:projectId'...`

Comment: this was a brilliant idea. but now as i´m trying to implement, and write a new $http request in my controller, all my scopes are looking like this {{ somescope.parameter }} ... why is that? Seems that I cant fire a second http.request.

Comment: what does your view have to do with the requests? And why can't you make second request? Have you looked for errors?

Comment: updated my initial post for you

Comment: listen to the network request in chrome and paste what you get

Comment: another edit for you

Comment: Misspelling of *success* here `$http.get('/uploads/media' + projectId).succes(function(data){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `.find` is incorrect in the get all function.

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find

```
Media.find({}, function (err, media){
    if (err) return next (err);
    res.json(media);
});
```

This will return all documents.

Comment: Updated my now working `.find ` to my initial post. Now I´m getting a 304 Status from `app.get('uploads/media/:projectId'...)`. The request now seems to work, but i can´t fetch an image

Comment: Have you checked the DB to make sure there is an object there? try https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo

Comment: Was using Postman for chrome all the time, because I just needed to read json data. I´m installing rockmongo right now

Comment: I´ve been trying installing rockmongo the whole day, but it failed. Is there another way to find out if there are any images in the database? When trying to get the data, i get this in my console: GET /uploads/media/[object%20Object] 304

Comment: I use mongohub. Here is a great list of GUIs http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/

Comment: OSX only tool, so I used NoSQL Manager. Here´s whats inside my mediaSchema ... looks like there are no images. http://imgur.com/MKjLDOk

Comment: Did my answer help you in the end?